# Why is Facebook Conversions API needed to keep tracking users after the sunsetting of third-party cookies?

Tags: facebook, cookies, facebook-pixel, facebook-conversions-api, conversions-api

I hope this question is on-topic here, as it's about the tech side of the Facebook tracking.

Some months ago, Facebook released their Conversions API (CAPI) to make it possible to send them user activity events directly from your servers, instead of sending the events from the client using the classic Facebook pixel.

Supposedly, they released CAPI because the Facebook pixel uses third-party cookies to identify the user, and at some point in 2023 Google Chrome will start blocking third-party cookies. This change should render the client-side Facebook pixel useless, supposedly, or at least that's what every marketing blog out there says.

The thing is, from what I can see in my browser devtools, the Facebook pixel inserts a cookie named `_fbp` on a first-party context (and also another one named `_fbc` if the visitor landed on the website from a Facebook ad). These two cookies are unique to the user and the website. Then, the Facebook pixel attaches the cookie values as query params to the GET request that does to the Facebook servers on every event.

So, if the Facebook pixel is generating and reading these first-party cookies & attaching them as query params on every event, what's the deal with Conversions API? Supposedly it should solve the problem of third-party cookies blocking, but we're not using third-party cookies here, and anyway we are attaching the value to the cookie in the URL instead of sending the values in the cookie headers.

I guess I'm misunderstanding something. Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Without 3rd-party cookies, how would Facebook know _which_ user this actually is? All they would be able to do, is accumulate data based on a random identifier across your site only. That does not allow them to match this data to any actual user in their system - which is rather the point of all that tracking and privacy invasion to begin with though.

Comment: Hi @CBroe! The thing is, the pixel is NOT using third-party cookies currently, if I checked my devtools correctly (maybe I'm wrong here). That's why this is puzzling me. I have the hypothesis that they match you using a combination of the _fbc cookie (which is an ID of a a click on ad, so they know the FB account which clicked) and some other fingerprinting techniques.

Comment: But the pixel code makes a request to Facebook, so if that's a cross-domain request with the `credentials` flag set, it would also send the cookies your browser has stored for `facebook.com`.

Comment: Hi! I'm not seeing such credentials flah set (do you have more info about it, or a link?). Do you find any example of website where the Facebook pixel is setting the cookies third-party or is sending them anyway with a flag like `credentials`?

Comment: No, I have not looked into it in detail yet.

Comment: Hi @TheMrAngel Could you let me know if you got any more info on this? I'm also trying to better understand it

Comment: Hi @kufer Sadly not! I didn't return to this topic again. If you happen to find the answer, would you please share it here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic in the question is entirely correct; I think the confusion mostly stems from terminology.

Facebook posts [like this one](https://www.facebook.com/business/news/how-conversions-api-gets-businesses-closer-to-customers) don't compare third-party cookies with first-party cookies; instead, they compare them to *first-party data*. This term typically refers to the data customers provide voluntarily, such as emails and phone numbers entered in forms, as well as persistent user identifiers that may be used by the app or a store.

When a pixel tracks an event with JavaScript code, it indeed has access to the current `_fbp` cookie, which may be relatable to a paid ad click or it might be from a different device, for example. For instance, if the event tracked is on the thank you page after a purchase, there would often be no personally identifiable information available there.

Contrastingly, it's all available server-side. If a customer has signed up on the website previously, the server would have the original click ID, name, email, and so forth. So in many cases, server-side integration would have a lot more data to attribute the conversion, compared to Pixel tracking.

In other words, it isn't the type of cookies; it's the presence of additional data on the server that may be useful to attribute the conversion if the `_fbp` cookie is unhelpful.

First-party cookies become a limitation in a sense that in the ideal (for ad platforms) world, where cross-domain third-party cookies would've always been available and there would be no need for `_fbp` first-party cookie because the tracking pixel has access to the facebook.com cookies on any website. Third-party cookies like this are still partially available in Chrome ([until 2024](https://privacysandbox.com/open-web/#the-privacy-sandbox-timeline)), but hasn't been available in Safari for years.

Thus, first-party cookies plus a server-side integration is where the industry moved. First-party cookies may be entirely sufficient for a website where customers buy immediately and never return, but for anything else, they're a serious limitation.

A Conversions API integration that ensures it has access to the original click ID, cookies, personal data, etc. (instead of attempting to proxy the Pixel requests via the first-party domain in the hope that tracking blockers won't notice, as many do) can make a huge difference in the Ads Manager data.

Comment: Spot on. The problem is, while that Facebook post talks about first-party data and server-to-server integrations, much of the industry is still thinking in terms of what CAPI can do to improve a Client-Side-only facebook set up. I keep getting asked to use Javascript to send client-side events to CAPI, with no server integration to back them up. Folks are entirely missing the point: CAPI provides value when you set up your server to send first party data. It won't magically fix your client-side tracking.

Answer (score 0):

It's not just about first vs third party. Even first-party cookies, if set by JavaScript instead of a secure server, are impacted by Apple's ITP, which will expire any such cookies after 7 days.

Comment: Still, the question remains with Chrome: why do they say that Facebook CAPI solves the third-party cookies tracking limitations, when we were already using first-party cookies values attached to the GET request as query params?

Comment: The author probably alluded to the fact that [JS-set cookies had shorter expiration cap compared to server-set cookies](https://www.simoahava.com/privacy/first-party-cookies-webkit-revisited/) in WebKit browsers in the past, which is no longer the case

Comment: @Paul The limitation definitely still exists- if you read Simo's article you linked to, you'll see he says "This does not mean that WebKit rolled back the change from ITP 2.1. Rather, it means that WebKit is converging the restrictions placed on all script-writable storage, which includes JavaScript cookies." 
Simo also maintains https://www.cookiestatus.com/, which agrees: cookies set with JavaScript expire after 7 days of no interaction in Safari. Server-set 1st party cookies don't have that restriction.

Comment: @TheMrAngel They say it because it sounds good to people who don't really understand the nuances of cookie restrictions. You're right- it definitely doesn't "solve third-party cookie limitations", nor is the problem they're trying to solve really just a "third-party cookie limitation"; but at least for Safari, having a server-set first party cookie is more reliable than facebook's current JS first party cookie

Comment: @Jenn, you are right and I should've been more precise in my comment. I was speaking in the original context that was describing script-writable cookies sent to CAPI. sGTM or FB CAPI Gateway often used to send conversions to FB CAPI won't help with that. While sGTM can set its own HttpOnly cookie, except from the 7-day restriction, I don't believe it's used by its integration with the CAPI. Even if it was, in a typical setup would be limited to 7 days by the ITP anti-cloaking. It only really works with a server aware of first-party data, typically meaning own code or a CDP that supports this.